# Straightforward way to downscale too large video with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm using GStreamer to process videos in my project. The input videos can have various formats (both resolutions and aspect-ratio). It can be for example 400x300, 1080p, 4K, 2000x1000, etc.

I would like to downscale videos automatically which are larger than 1080p. So if video is in 4K it should be downscaled to 1080p but if it is in 400x300 format it should be kept in original format.

I've found [videoscale](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoconvertscale/videoscale.html) pipeline plugin but it does not work as I would like. It is changing scale up and down without any distinctions. Also it is not changing sizes proportionally when only width or height is provided.

Do you know any straightforward way in GStreamer to downscale resolutions automatically to desired size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GStreamer's caps allow ranges. So I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
video/x-raw,width=[1,1920],height=[1,1080],pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1
```

This will keep the same aspect ratio but scales down in case it is required to fit into 1920x1080.

E.g.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=4000,height=2000 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=[1,1920],height=[1,1080],pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! autovideosink
```

Will be scaled down to 1920x960.

And:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=400,height=200 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=[1,1920],height=[1,1080],pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! autovideosink
```

Will stay at 400x200.

Comment: Perfect! It works exactly like I wanted! Thanks!

@FlorianZwoch please explain me one thing - where the heck this is documented? I blindly went through https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/ to find where is described that I can use ranges like `width=[1,1920]` and what does it mean when I use the range? How it behave? I couldn't find a straight answer.

The broader question: is there a clearer source of knowledge about GStreamer than the mentioned documentation?

Comment: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html#caps here maybe. It appears in different areas as well. Maybe more in the plugin writer section.

Comment: Caps control capabilities. With these caps filters you can further control whats happening. Depending on the elements implementation they can try to fulfill these restrictions. E.g. videoscale selects a resolution that fits into the caps. You can control many things with it, e.g. whether a webcam delivers raw images or jpeg encoded samples.

Comment: "Depending on the elements implementation" part is crucial here. The problem from my point of view is that for example docs of videoscale (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoconvertscale/videoscale.html) does not show/describe precisely what happen if I set only `width` or `height`, what happen if I set `integer` value, what if `range`, what if I add `pixel-aspect-ratio`.